# Send Record to a Child Window and Return Changed data in MVVM Pattern

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light

I want send selected record to child window in Mvvm design pattern(Silverlight Application).
how can i pass the selected record to child windows with messenger class of MVVM light toolkit **and get changed data**!?

Comment: just send a message with the selected records data and in the child view model subscribe to the messenger to receive messages and if you get the message load your new/changed data accordingly.

Comment: Please any Example.any link .tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this small example Jesse Liberty explains how to send and receive messages with Galasoft MVVM messenger.

[Jesse Liberty Example](http://jesseliberty.com/2011/01/06/windows-phone-from-scratch%E2%80%93mvvm-light-toolkit-soup-to-nuts-3/)

If you follow this small example you will be able to implement your own scenario with it.

Comment: perfect.And also i can send data to a other page or other form with messaging.but i don't know how can i return data from child form!!!

Comment: you could create a Reply message. :)